# SQL Select omitting results from a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join, not-exists

I have the following code which, when run separately, produces the results I expect but when run collectively returns nothing:

```
SELECT SurveyUID FROM   tbSurvey AS tbS
WHERE  NOT EXISTS   
(SELECT tbS.SurveyUID
FROM         tbSurvey AS tbS INNER JOIN
                  tbSurveyElementCategory AS tbSEC ON tbS.SurveyUID = tbSEC.SurveyUID INNER JOIN
                  tbElementCategory AS tbEC ON tbSEC.ElementCategoryID = tbEC.ElementCategoryID
WHERE     (tbEC.ElementCategoryID = 75))
```

The first line returns 185 records and the sub-query returns 20 records as a sub-set of the first query. I am trying to return the 165 records that don't appear in the sub-query. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot put **tbS.SurveyUID = tbS1.SurveyUID** condition

Try this:

```
SELECT SurveyUID 
FROM   tbSurvey AS tbS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT tbS1.SurveyUID
                  FROM tbSurvey AS tbS1 
                  INNER JOIN tbSurveyElementCategory AS tbSEC ON tbS1.SurveyUID = tbSEC.SurveyUID 
                  INNER JOIN tbElementCategory AS tbEC ON tbSEC.ElementCategoryID = tbEC.ElementCategoryID
                  WHERE (tbEC.ElementCategoryID = 75) AND tbS.SurveyUID = tbS1.SurveyUID
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. You have to write: `...WHERE SurveyUID NOT IN (...subquery...)`. In your query you say "give me all ID-s if the subquery has no results" but it has results.